# calendar icon doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using jquery ui datepicker this way:

```
$('<input type="text" />').datepicker({
    buttonImage: "http://localhost:2000/proj/styles/calendar/images/calendar/cal.gif"
}).appendTo(container);
```

This path "http://localhost:2000/proj/styles/calendar/images/calendar/cal.gif" leads to an image. I checked it.

when this code executes, I ends up with working date picker that doesn't have an icon. If i focusing the text box, a calendar appear.

Why doesn't the calendar icon show up?

Comment: What happens when you put that URL directly into the browser address field?

Comment: Do you need to refer to the image using its fully-qualified domain name? I'd use '/proj/styles/calendar/images/calendar/cal.gif' if your page is on the same server.

Comment: @Pointy: It shows the image in the browser.

Comment: Is it happening in all browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `showOn` option to either `button` or `both` for the icon to show up.

Also, I think the datepicker has a hard time adding the icon before the input is on the DOM tree. So, you should consider swap the `appendTo()` and `datepicker()` calls:

```
$('<input type="text" />').appendTo(container)).datepicker({
    buttonImage: "icon url",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    showOn: 'button'
});
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/GyP2u/1/.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the option will only actived when u focus the input, because as default is `showOn: 'focus'`

so, check changing this line:

```
buttonImage: '', // URL for trigger button image
```

in the main source of datepicker (default: `jquery.ui.datepicker.js`)